# How to restrict a input in jsp to take only alphabets without using JavaScripts (as JavaScripts are disabled)?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

My input tag in my JSP page is `<input type="text" name="firstName" id="fName" />`. How can I force the field to accept only alpha characters? If the user presses any key other than LETTERS, it should not enter it into the text field.

Answer (score 1):

Most of today's browsers support HTML5, which allows specific input characteristics i.e.,

```
<input type="number" .. />
```

will allow only digits as an input.

For the text only, you will need to use pattern:

```
<input type="text" name="name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]" />
```

For more info visit [HTML5](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/) documentation

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflaw. When you accept the answer click the check mark on the left. Thx

Comment: Is there any changes in Eclipse required to run HTML5

Comment: I am not sure as I am not using Eclipse.